# How to find internet traffic coming from a specific source?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

I am working on a GA project and one of my tasks is to find visitors that come from the GE Stock Quote page in yahoo finance to our website. I tried custom report with the dimensions source/medium and referral path. I then used an advanced filter to specify Referral path containing finance.yahoo.com/quote but my results are coming up empty.

I understand that its possible that there may be no visitors from that specific page but I want  to rule out that the null results are because of user error.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the link yourself and see if you see if your activity comes up in your custom report. You can add one more dimension 'city' to make sure its you in the custom report.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion here are the steps:

- You need to go to the Referrals report.
- Add *secondary dimension* --> **`hostname`**.
- Filter this hostname with ***finance.yahoo.com***. You will see all the traffic from this domain

***How to find the users/visitors coming from this domain?***

- If you have client id as a custom dimension, create the custom report with the above-mentioned steps and add the client id as the dimension.
- To ensure, you can never ever target the particular users. ;)